# Resize no Captcha Recaptcha

Tags: css, recaptcha

I'm implementing the new "No Captcha Recaptcha" in my site.

The problem is that it is not narrow enough, and I want to change it's width...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use their tag attribute `data-size` which you can set to `compact` eg:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-size="compact" data-sitekey="XXXX"></div>
```

Have a look at the docs page under Configuration, g-recaptcha tag attributes and grecaptcha.render parameters 
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Comment: it's about time that they enable that :)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can use CSS transform property to scale it. Found this solution at this website https://www.geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/ which seems to be scale the initial captcha container.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="light" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" style="transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0;-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;transform-origin:0 0; 0"></div>
```